# Conversion from milliseconds to DateTime format

Tags: c#, datetime

I got a string which is representend like this :

```
string startdatetime = "13988110600000"
```

What I want to do is to convert this string (which are milliseconds) to a DateTime variable. This is what I'm doing :

```
double ticks = double.Parse(startdatetime);
TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(ticks);
DateTime startdate = new DateTime(time.Ticks);
```

The result is almost good : I've got a weird date but time is okay (30/04/**0045** 18:00:00).

Is there any reason to this?

Comment: What is it the number of milliseconds from? It looks like a Unix time stamp, so you would want to get the time that is x milliseconds after 1/1/1970, rather than from 0

Comment: DateTime ts = new DateTime(1970,1,1).AddMilliseconds(x)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

`DateTime` in .NET is initialized to `0001-01-01 00:00:00` and then you add your `TimeSpan`, which seems to be 45 Years.

It is common for such (milli)-second time definitions to start at `1970-01-01 00:00:00`, so maybe the following gives you the expected result:

```
double ticks = double.Parse(startdatetime);
TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(ticks);
DateTime startdate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1) + time;
```

or simply

```
var date = (new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).AddMilliseconds(double.Parse(startdatetime));
```

Comment: Since .NET 4.6 (not available when you wrote your answer), it is more pretty to use `var startdate = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(long.Parse(startdatetime)).UtcDateTime;` or similar. The convention of using 1970 January 01 as the "epoch", they call `UnixTime`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen your comment should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that your value is based on milliseconds elapsed since `01/01/1900` or `01/01/1970` and DateTime in C# starts with `01/01/00001`.

I think it starts from `01/01/1970` because 1970 + 45 would be 2015 which I think it is the year you search.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In fact 2014 is the year I wanted but it's okay, you were right !

Answer (score 4):

Since [`TimeSpan.Ticks` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.ticks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns `long`, your `new DateTime(time.Ticks)` code call [`DateTime(long)` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk.aspx) and from it's documentation;

> A date and time expressed in the number of 100-nanosecond intervals
>   that have elapsed **since January 1, 0001 at 00:00:00.000 in the
>   Gregorian calendar**.

That's why it's wrong to say *The result is almost good*. The value of result is expected as implemented and documented.

Comment: Iv'e tried this  :

1477484505102   results in ->  10/27/0047 12:21:45 PM

Answer (score 0):

Get *Now* in milliseconds:

`DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()`

```
yourDateTime.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(
    new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
).TotalMilliseconds
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I understand your value is measured like a Unix Timestamp. As commented in other (deprecated) answers, there is an utility you can use and avoids you to "count" from 01/01/1970 (I always forget that date...)

With your variable `string startdatetime = "13988110600000"`

```
long elapsed_ms = long.Parse(startdatetime);
DateTime date = 
   DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(elapsed_ms).UtcDateTime;
```

Add try/catch and different values for the initial variable as you wish and you are done