# CalendarView can not setdate to current day?

Tags: android, calendarview

Every time I try to set `CalendarView` to focus today (use setDate() to set), it always shows the last day which is available in the Calendar (31 November 2100).

But if i set date to another day it's work fine.

```
CalendarView cal = new CalendarView(this);
cal.setDate(new Date().getTime(),false,true);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
CalendarView cal = new CalendarView(this);
cal.setDate(System.currentTimeMillis(),false,true);
```

or

```
cal.setDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(),false,true);
```

Comment: What does this code have to do with setting a day in the `CalendarView` class?

Answer (score 1):

This is waste of time + headache thing ,I really wonder why there are no one here answer this topic (3years ago!) /or why there is no any top search result in Google to answer this simple problem.

It's too sad that I can't never explain my rage with my bad English skill,
**So I will just write it here for the other that will face this issue.**

To convert DateTime of C#  for Calendar View -> You must subtract tick count of this date 1/1/1970

```
public static long DatetimeToLong(DateTime dt) {
        return  (long)( dt - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds  ;
        //(dt  - (new DateTime(1970, 1, 1) )  );
    }

Calendar_View.SetDate( util.DatetimeToLong(DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(20) )  ,false ,true);
```

p.s. [Conversion from milliseconds to DateTime format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23381870/conversion-from-milliseconds-to-datetime-format)