# 1515628800000 convert into datetime formate in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Get Result from json file.
How To convert this object type "1515628800000" into C# Date Time format.
i tried to this method but it give me exception.

```
DateTime.ParseExact(item.StartDate, @"dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: well yes - you told it to find dd/MM/yyyy and then gave it just a long string of numbers!

Comment: Is `1515628800000` in milliseconds instead of concrete `DateTime`? You need to use date format string if you want using `DateTime.ParseExact`. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23381870/conversion-from-milliseconds-to-datetime-format) if you want to convert milliseconds to `DateTime`.

Comment: `1515628800000` Where is the Year, Month,Day and time? If you determine one those then you can create a complete datetime using substring.