# Parsing a integer using DateTime.ParseExact

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to parse a integer(like 43392) to a date time.

The code looks like this:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(item[11], "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

wher item[11] is "43392".

This throws an System.FormatException error, string was not recognized as a valid Datetime.

Need some guidance on this.

Comment: 43392 doesnt seems to be a date. What is your expected output?

Comment: 43392 is a excel number for date. trying to convert it to a date like 17/Oct/2018.

Comment: Does that number represent that date?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23381870/conversion-from-milliseconds-to-datetime-format (if the value represents integer milliseconds).

Comment: why do you think that 43392 is 17/Oct/2018?

Comment: For those, like myself, in the dark: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/datevalue-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252

Comment: @vasily.sib it is from excel and i tried converting it.

Comment: I am not sure if you are looking for [convert an Excel serial date number to a .NET DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/727495/3796048)

Comment: @Corak Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727466/how-do-i-convert-an-excel-serial-date-number-to-a-net-datetime.

Comment: Yeah there is a million duplicates to this, hrmm which one should i pick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.FromOADate(43392);
```

**Output**

```
19/10/2018 12:00:00 AM
```

---

[DateTime.FromOADate Method (Double)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Returns a DateTime equivalent to the specified OLE Automation Date.