# How to convert Date Value to DateTime DataType

Tags: c#

I have an Json string with Date Column Created_Date whose value is **1596886142038**

I would like to know how to convert these value to DateTime DataType.

Updated:-

Value : 1596886142038
Return date value : {09-08-0051 00:00:00}

Comment: Convert them on deserialization or after the fact ? Also this question is fairly low quality, please read the help on asking questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code convert to datetime.

```
TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1596886142038);
DateTime value =  new DateTime(1970, 1, 1) + time;
```

Hope to help you!

Comment: It working,but please check my value in above comments

Comment: Yes, It begin from 1970/01/01.  So need to update like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23381870/conversion-from-milliseconds-to-datetime-format . I updated!