# convert to DateTime long int |.C#

Tags: c#, datetime

In my api response I have key such long int type.

```
{
  "1640908800000": 123945000000,
  "1648684800000": 97278000000,
  "1656547200000": 82959000000,
  "1664496000000": 90146000000,
  "index": "TableIndex"
},
{
  "1640908800000": 69702000000,
  "1648684800000": 54719000000,
  "1656547200000": 47074000000,
  "1664496000000": 52051000000,
  "index": "BookIndex"
}
```

`1664496000000` key It must be DateTime. I didn't see such example. According my api and information from website it must be `9/29/2022`

How I can parse it to normal `DateTime` Format?

Comment: [Conversion from milliseconds to DateTime format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23381870/conversion-from-milliseconds-to-datetime-format)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be Unix timestamp in milliseconds, to convert it to `DateTime` you need to parse it as long and then process for example with `DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds`:

```cs
DateTime dt = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(long.Parse("1664496000000"))
    .UtcDateTime;
Console.WriteLine(dt); // Prints "9/30/2022 12:00:00 AM"
```

Answer (score 3):

That looks like Unix timestamp so this is how you can convert it to datetime:

```
DateTimeOffset dateTime = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(timestamp);
```